# SQL Summary of revenues by region (in ranked order from highest to lowest, calculate % of total for each region)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Summary of revenues by region (in ranked order from highest to lowest, calculate % of total for each region). Basically, I am trying to write a query that will show the revenues of each region relative to the total revenue.

I am using SQL in Microsoft Access.

My table has the following columns: ID, Region, Revenue

There are 3 regions: West, Central, East

Heres what I have so far:

```
SELECT Region, Sum(Revenue) AS TotalRevenue
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(Revenue) DESC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that I'd offer, for only three regions its really overkill, but it should work.

```
SELECT Region, Sum(Revenue) AS TotalRevenue, Sum(Revenue)/x.allRegionRevenue
FROM Sales s,
inner join (select sum(revenue) allRegionRevenue)) x
   on s.revenue*0 = x.allRegionRevenue*0
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(Revenue) DESC
```

**Edit: ** Modified this a bit as Access doesn't support actual "cross join" syntax, but I think we can "fake" it with an inner join on a condition that's always true - klugey trick here is merely to multiply references from each to zero forcing all recs to match. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Region, SUM(Revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
       (SUM(Revenue)/(SELECT Sum(Revenue) FROM Sales)) AS percentage
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Sum(Revenue) DESC
```